# app not running on startup with no error

Tags: android, service, startup

this app will run on startup and monitor clipboard for changes and do somthings ;)

but it not run on startup :(

I search whole web for solution but I can't fix it.

This is AndroidManifest.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.TB.Zedit"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.TB.Zedit.ActMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>

               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

               <data android:mimeType="text/*" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".service_starter" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<service android:name=".clipboard_monitor"></service>

</application>
```

I want to my app run on startup and create a service but nothing happen

my app not run with no error; I'm really confused

this is my `service_starter` code

```
package com.TB.Zedit;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class service_starter extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {
        ComponentName clipboard_monitor_service=context.startService(new Intent("com.TB.Zedit.clipboard_monitor"));

        if (clipboard_monitor_service==null)
        {
            Log.e("Zedit", "unable to start service");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("Zedit", "service STARTED");

        }
    }
}
}
```

catlog

```
10-07 03:30:59.280: D/asset(1177): failed to open Zip archive '/data/app/com.TB.Zedit-2.apk'
10-07 03:30:59.280: W/PackageParser(1177): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-2.apk
10-07 03:30:59.300: W/PackageSettings(1177): Skipping PackageSetting{b300fd20 com.TB.Zedit/10054} due to missing metadata
10-07 03:30:59.620: W/PackageSettings(1177): Skipping PackageSetting{b300fd20 com.TB.Zedit/10054} due to missing metadata
10-07 03:31:08.090: W/ActivityManager(1177): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Zedit.apk
10-07 03:31:08.090: W/ActivityManager(1177): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Zedit.apk
10-07 03:31:08.200: I/PackageManager(1177): Running dexopt on: com.TB.Zedit
10-07 03:31:08.200: I/PackageManager(1177): Package com.TB.Zedit codePath changed from /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-2.apk to /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-07 03:31:08.310: I/ActivityManager(1177): Force stopping com.TB.Zedit appid=10054 user=-1: update pkg
10-07 03:31:08.310: W/PackageManager(1177): Code path for pkg : com.TB.Zedit changing from /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-2.apk to /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-1.apk
10-07 03:31:08.310: W/PackageManager(1177): Resource path for pkg : com.TB.Zedit changing from /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-2.apk to /data/app/com.TB.Zedit-1.apk
10-07 03:31:08.470: D/BackupManagerService(1177): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.TB.Zedit flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
```

Comment: Your service and receiver names are equals. This is a service naming error.

Comment: Show your code and logcat please.

Comment: still NOT working :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i sloved this problem

for recive ON_BOOT_COMPLETED by an app, app must have 2 feature:

1: app must have at least one activity

2: app must run with user at least for one time

Answer (score 0):

Add this to launch your desired activity in between the activity tag.Suppose, you want to launch this activity when your application starts :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.TB.Zedit.ActMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>``
</activity>
```

Comment: He want to start a Service after BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: It will run the service as well as he is declared the service on the manifest but to show ui he has to do this what i have done.He has also requirement of getting ui what he is doing not setting any launcher, by doing this he can view ui

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your manifest,

you have used this:

```
<receiver android:name=".service_starter" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"  />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".service_starter"></service>
```

Change the name according to which one is Service and which one is BroadcastReceiver.

You would need a broadcast receiver to start your application.

Example:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And now, create a class MyReceiver.java in your default package, which will extend a `BroadcastReceiver` like shown below:

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActMain.class);
        intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent );
    }
}
```

You can read more here: [Start activity or service on boot](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/start-activity-or-service-on-boot.html)

Hope this helps.